# The extension 'amp-mustache' is referenced at version '0.1' which is a deprecated version Use a more recent version of this extension

Tags: amp-html, deprecation-warning, amp-mustache

google search console is throwing a warning for my amp page which is having the script '

```
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js";></script>
```

'and the mustache documentation https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-mustache is showing that the version 0.2 is available. Will just changing the version will index my page correctly without showing any errors or warnings in the google search console

Answer (score 4):

**Change the script:**

```
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
```

Form details [Click Here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-mustache)